# Alink (Assembly) - Relocs x: Warning 32 bit offset in 16 bit field

Tags: winapi, assembly, x86, linker, nasm

When I try to link my with `Nasm` compiled code using `Alink` then I get the Error `Relocs x:Warning 32 bit offset in 16 bit field`. This error disappears if I remove the .text Section from the code.

Does not work:

```
section .text USE32
..start:
mov eax, ebx ;just example code
ret
```

Does work:

```
..start:
mov eax, ebx ;just example code
ret
```

Comment: What command (format) did you use for `nasm`?

Comment: `nasm -f obj file_name.asm`

Comment: Alink Command: `alink -oPE -subsys con file_name.obj`

Comment: The second version generates 16 bit code. It does not "work" it just happens to link. No idea what format alink accepts but try `nasm -f win32` if you intend to produce 32 bit windows binaries.

Comment: @Jester Now that that is fixed, I get the error `error: parser: instruction expected`. The lines that are marked as errors contain function imports:
`import printf msvcrt.dll`. I also used `extern printf` one line before.

Comment: [edit] your question to show the current code. Possibly ask a different question if it's a different error.

Comment: Apparently `import` only works for `obj`. For `win32` you just `extern printf` and then link with the library ... I think.

Comment: If you go back to `obj` you might just be missing `[BITS 32]` from the top of your file.

Comment: @Jester Now the import errors are gone but I get the error `error: parser: instruction expected` at the lines that contain the sections (e.g. `.section data`).

Comment: nasm doesn't use a dot on `.section`. It's just `section`. The dot goes on the name, e.g. `section .data`.

Comment: @Jester The nasm command works now but alink gives out following error: `Unresolved external x`, where x are some winapi functions.

Comment: Did you link against the library containing those functions? Did you use the proper name? If winapi, that usually includes the ansi `A` or wide `W` suffix and/or the stdcall `@bytes`

Comment: @Jester How do I do that? With my initial approach those problems were solved by using `import`. Do I have to add each function to the nasm command to link it? And if yes how would an example command look like?

Comment: No, you only need to add the libraries and not to the `nasm` command but to the link command.